# What are the proper unit types for the calculation of the frequency of a tuning fork?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, waves, acoustics, frequency

[Wikipedia Article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuning_fork#Calculation_of_frequency)

The formula states that the calculation of the frequency with cylindrical tines should be

$$1.875^2/(2\pi L^2)\times(Er^2 /(4P))^{1/2}$$

where the variables are found in the wiki page just below the definition of the equation. Doing the algebra (starting with $1/m^2 \times (Pa \times m^2 / (kg / m^3))^{1/2})$ only with the unit types I wind up with $\frac{(Pa \times m^3)}{kg}$. Is this correct, and if so, how can I convert it to Hz?

Comment: I think $L$ needs to be squared in your first formula?

Comment: When you post in Physics Stack Exchange do not use links as part of the question. Questions must be self-contained. Take whatever equations and definitions you need from the Wiki article and type them into your question. There are several reasons for this: 1) It makes it much easier for us to understand what you're asking, 2) it avoids link rot, 3) in deciding what information is relevant you'll likely figure out the answer to your own question. Please do this to improve this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check your algebra. You actually end up with units $\sqrt{\frac{m\cdot Pa}{kg}}$.

Now, one Pascal is one Netwon per meter squared, $Pa=\frac{N}{m^2}$. One Newton is one kilogram-meter per second squared, $N=\frac{kg\cdot m}{s^2}$. Thus one Pascal is $Pa=\frac{kg}{m \cdot s^2}$, and if we plug that into $\sqrt{\frac{m \cdot Pa}{kg}}$ we get units of $\frac{1}{s}$, or $Hz$.